# MSVC cannot send function parameters of 16byte alignment on x86

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm using MSVC to use some SSE intrinsics. In order to support this I aligned some of my data at a 16byte boundary. However, now that I compile for x86 instead of x64, MSVC insists that it is illegal for me to align a function parameter to 16bytes. But if that's true then how can anyone ever send SSE data types as function parameters?

So how can I send 16byte aligned parameters in a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if that's true then how can anyone ever send SSE data types as function parameters?

You can't. :)
Under Microsoft's ABI, you have to pass it by reference or pointer.

One workaround may be to use the [fastcall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xa169sk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) calling convention which, apparently, passes the first few SSE arguments in XMM registers.

Comment: I guess the natural followup question is "Can't the compiler do this transformation for me?".

Comment: Bleh, you beat me to this. Reference is here: According to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthk2dkh.aspx

Comment: @Mysticial: that's the docs for the x64 calling convention. He's asking about x86 :)

Comment: @Mysticial: Yeah, the reason I had a nasty shock is because it worked fine in x64.

Comment: Speaking of the x64 calling convention, I find it hilariously stupid that it doesn't *under any circumstances* allows you to pass SSE arguments in the XMM registers. Now that they finally have a hard guarantee that the XMM registers are available, they decide not to use them

Comment: And now that I have passed everything by const reference... it still dies. x86 y u fail and x64 doesn't?

Comment: x64 uses 16-byte alignment on the stack by default, so it works there. Not sure why passing by const ref still fails

Comment: Perhaps your variables aren't correctly aligned to 16-bytes in their original, local definition?